# sql relationships table

Tags: sql

Just want to ask a question when create relationship between table.

If I want to create relationship between tableA and tableB.
I can see there are different way to do it.
Just want to understand what is the pro or con for these way.

**1. another table to link both tableA and tableB together**

```
Create Table tableA (
tableA_id int
)

Create Table tableB(
tableB_id int
)

Create table tableA_B(
tableA_id int,
tableB_id int
)
```

**2. Add tableB_id in tableA to link them togther**

```
Create Table tableA (
tableA_id int,
tableB_id int
)

Create Table tableB(
tableB_id int
)
```

Sorry about my poor english :(

Hope I explained well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 1, you create the third table because A and B have a many to many relationship.
In 2, Table A and B have a 1 to many relationship.